# Database table design for a user referencing a particular outcome

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

[image]
Scenario:
The user inputs name, goal, and size.  Goals are "long", "average", "short".  Sizes are "big", "medium", "small".  There are 3 tables.  `User` stores name, goal, and size of each user. `Final` stores outcome based on goal/size combination.  `UserFinal` serves as an associate table that stores the appropriate user with corresponding outcome.  A certain combination of goal and size results in a specific outcome (refer to the table below) that is assigned to that user.

```
GOAL        SIZE    OUTCOME
Long        Big     12
Long        Medium  14
Long        Small   18
Average     Big     13
Average     Medium  16
Average     Small   19
Short       Big     15
Short       Medium  17
Short       Small   20
```

Objective:  Table `Final` should not grow and is only intended to serve as a 'lookup' table for when a User submits their goal and size (not sure if a table that isn't expected to grow is a good design?).  The `outcome` value will be used for further calculations for each particular user.

Question:  Is the illustrated table design the correct way to reflect this scenario?  If it isn't, what is the best way for accomplishing this?

Comment: Goal and Size in User seems to be redundant

Comment: @Tassadaque - agreed, but I am not sure how to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Goal and Size identifies Outcome, and each User sets one Outcome.
See the following data model:

[image: DM]

Sample data:

```
Goal
--------
L  Long
A  Average
S  Short
```

```
Size
--------
B  Big
M  Medium
S  Small
```

```
Outcome
--------
L  B  12
L  M  14
L  S  18
A  B  13
A  M  16
A  S  19
S  B  15
S  M  17
S  S  20
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my answer and am submitting another one, because the edits changed the clarity of the question significantly.

**Have a final table purely as a look-up table does not seem like good db design.**

I would do a simple one to many relationship.

Every `user` has many `outcomes` like so:

### Users

```
user_id [pk]
name
```

### Outcomes

```
outcome_id [pk]
user_id [fk]
goal
size
outcome
```

Comment: I am following what you are saying, but how will the `outcome` column be populated after the user submits their `goal` and `size`?  How will the `outcome` column know which value to use?

Comment: Whatever system your user is submitting their goal and size thru can contain the logic to update the outcome field. DBs are used to store records of observations for the most part, but in this context, outcome is a calculated field that can be created from the data already stored in the database (goal and size).